# How to test the quality of random data

Tags: bash, random, fips

I think I found a way to generate large amounts of truly random bytes. How can I test the quality of the generated data? I've already used **rngtest** (which is based on the FIPS specifications) and it showed good results, however it doesn't look like a complete test: I've made some experiments and not truly random data performs well too: I tested the output from /dev/urandom and worse the MD5 hashes of consecutive numbers (a very predictable and low entropy input).

If more tests prove that the data is good, how valuable would them be? Could I make money out of it?

Comment: Answer to last part first - No. `man getrandom`. There are a multitude of papers and open-source high-quality random number generators. Your learning and experience are always valuable, just not always monetarily. True education is that part that remains after all that you've learned has been forgotten...

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I forgot to mention that it is not a PRNG but rather it generates random bytes gathering real-word data. Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

It is not so complicated. Just run [dieharder](https://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php) test by Robert G. Brown.

Answer (score 1):

Reasonably good test is [TestU01](http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html) from prof P. L'Ecuyer.

Wrt how valuable it could be, you'd better ask OS/system library developers in companies like MS or Apple